# Windows-7 wireless adapter gone missing

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

My wireless adapter is "Intel Centrino Advanced N 6200 AGN" Sometimes wireless connects and sometimes the wireless adapter is totally missing (from the device manager itself). Even after doing a "scan for hardware changes" in device manager does not bring back the wireless adapter. There is no way of enabling it. Sometimes upon restart I get my wireless adapter back but sometimes even restart doesnt help. 
I tried "update driver" when wireless adapter worked on restart, but, windows says the driver is up to date.

Comment: Does your laptop have a switch to disable the wifi? This may make the device disappear in Windows.

Comment: The switch is turned ON. I re-installed windows 7, even then I don't see the wireless adapter. Before re-installation the adapter appeared intermittently, but after re-installation it totally disappeared.