# Empty network adapters list in network connections (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7

**Question:** How can I get the wireless adapters list to show up on Network connections window?

---

Recently I have noticed the following icon on **windows 7** system tray. Ironically this has no effect on connecting to the network.

[image: Ethernet Icon]

Typically the device will display the following Icon on system tray.

[image: Wireless Icon]

In the Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections there is no adapters display. Below is the current status.

[image: Network Connections]

Intel PROSet/Wireless tool test results

[image: Intel PROSet/Wireless Tool Test Results]

Status on current investigation:

I have tried in uninstall and reinstall the drivers. In the process I completely loss network connectivity. A restore system was done from a previous update to get back network connectivity (Not a pleasant experience)

I reinstall the drivers from manufacture with out much success.

When I open the device manager and click on the properties of the network adapters I see the following error.

[image: Network Adapter Error]

**Background:** I have been encountering windows update issues as described in [Windows 7 Update Failed on Multiple attempts](https://superuser.com/questions/1322413/windows-7-update-failed-on-multiple-attempts) post. Analyzing the cbs.log file has led me similar articles as follows [Fix Windows Update issues](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors) which reference a windows networking issue.

References:

- [How to troubleshoot missing network connections icons in Windows Server 2003 and in Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/825826/how-to-troubleshoot-missing-network-connections-icons-in-windows-serve)
- [Windows-7 wireless adapter gone missing](https://superuser.com/questions/802212/windows-7-wireless-adapter-gone-missing?rq=1)

Comment: Have you confirmed method 2, step 2, in the troubleshooting document you linked to? Make sure all necessary services are running.

Comment: @Appleoddity, thank for the comment. I see and error. I have update the post with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be related to a corrupted registry. Follow are few suggestions

- Click Start and type `regedit`
- Save/Backup the current registry settings [Backup and restore the registry in Windows 7](https://neosmart.net/wiki/backup-restore-registry/#Backup_and_restore_the_registry_in_Windows_7)
- Alternatively you could go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Network`, right click on Network and export the Network folder only
- Select the Network folder. Select `config` variable from the right hand pane which has a binary value. Delete this variable.
  [image: Regedit - Config]
- Close the registry editor and open the network connection folder. Sometimes a re-boot might be necessary. 
  [image: Network connections folder]

Try this out. Hope this of help.